# Use .reduce to sum object variabele based on object enum

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm trying to use the .reduce method to sum the amount of different Expense objects. These Expenses can be of different type, and I'd like to keep the objects in the array splitted by that. So for example, the following array of expenses:

```
[
  {type: A, amount: 2},
  {type: A, amount: 1},
  {type: B, amount: 2},
  {type: A, amount: 3},
  {type: C, amount: 2},
  {type: B, amount: 1}
]
```

Should become this:

```
[
  {type: A, amount: 6},
  {type: B, amount: 3},
  {type: C, amount: 2}
]
```

Also note that there should not be amount: 0 if no expenses of that type are present, but just an expense less. So without expenses of type C, the result should look like:

```
[
  {type: A, amount: 6},
  {type: B, amount: 3}
]
```

This is how far I got:

```
    private joinExpenses(expenses: Expense[]): Expense[] {
    // Add all expenses amount splitted by payment type and store in object
    const expenseArrayAsObject = expenses.reduce(
        (expensesObject, item) => {
            const type = item.type;
            if (!expensesObject.hasOwnProperty(type)) {
                expensesObject[type] = {
                    type: type,
                    amount: {
                        amount: 0
                    } as Money
                } as Expense;
            }

            const expense: Expense = expensesObject[type];
            expense.amount.amount = expense.amount.amount + item.amount.amount;
            expensesObject[type] = expense;

            return expensesObject;
        },
        {} as { [key: string]: any }
    );

    // Convert object to array
    const joinedExpenses: Expense[] = [];
    for (const key in expenseArrayAsObject) {
        joinedExpenses.push(expenseArrayAsObject[key]);
    }

    return joinedExpenses;
}
```

This works, but I feel like mapping to the object first and converting that to an array is a step too much, and can be simplified. I can do some manipulation afterwards but I feel like I iterate through arrays too much.. I just don't see how. Can you help me?

Comment: What happened to `type: C` in the output?

Comment: I think you could do it with one loop by reducing to an array and using find in each iteration to look for an existing object of the current iterated type and either adding to or creating that object if it doesn't already exist. I don't have time right now to demo it though.

Comment: It sounds like a group-by followed by a sum, but as mentioned above, i am not too sure about the desired result currently.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, type: C should be there but it should not be there with amount = 0 if there are no type C's. Editing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as the following with `.reduce()` and `.find()` combination:

```js
const data = [
  {type: 'A', amount: 2},
  {type: 'A', amount: 1},
  {type: 'B', amount: 2},
  {type: 'A', amount: 3},
  {type: 'C', amount: 2},
  {type: 'B', amount: 1}
];

const result = data.reduce((a, c) => {
  const found = a.find(e => e.type === c.type);
  if (found) found.amount = found.amount + c.amount;      
  return found ? a : a.concat(c);
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need ?

```js
const array = [
    {type: 'A', amount: 2},
    {type: 'A', amount: 1},
    {type: 'B', amount: 2},
    {type: 'A', amount: 3},
    {type: 'C', amount: 2},
    {type: 'B', amount: 1}
];

const result = array.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const current = acc.find(el => el.type === item.type);

    if(!current) {
        acc.push(item)
    }else{
        current.amount += item.amount;
    }

    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside `reduce` callback use `findIndex` to check if an object exist in accumulator accray with same key. Then update the value of amount, else create the object

```js
let data = [{
    type: 'A',
    amount: 2
  },
  {
    type: 'A',
    amount: 1
  },
  {
    type: 'B',
    amount: 2
  },
  {
    type: 'A',
    amount: 3
  },
  {
    type: 'C',
    amount: 2
  },
  {
    type: 'B',
    amount: 1
  }
]

let newData = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let ifKeyExist = acc.findIndex((item) => {
    return item.type === curr.type;
  });
  if (ifKeyExist === -1) {
    acc.push({
      type: curr.type,
      amount: curr.amount
    });
  } else {
    acc[ifKeyExist].amount += curr.amount;
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) over the array using an object as an accumulator. Use the `type` as the key, and assign the new object to it. Then use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to grab the output you need.

```js
const data = [
  {type: 'A', amount: 2},
  {type: 'A', amount: 1},
  {type: 'B', amount: 2},
  {type: 'A', amount: 3},
  {type: 'C', amount: 2},
  {type: 'B', amount: 1}
];

const out = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, { type, amount }) => {

  // If type doesn't exist as a key on the accumulator
  // add it and set its value to a new object
  acc[type] = acc[type] || { type, amount: 0 };

  // Increment the object amount value
  acc[type].amount += amount;

  // Return the accumulator
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(out);
```